# How to make the background colour the full height of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the main content area have a background image/colour that fills the whole area, but so far have been unsucessful.

Please see http://drewclifton.com/dev/dashboard/

So far I have tried adding a `fill` class to the `container-fluid` classed div – and also tried the `page-content-wrapper` div...

```
.fill {
    height:100%;
    background:darkblue;
}
```

... But the background does not extend past the vertical height of the enclosed `#story-bar` div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a percentage height, the height of `.fill` is *relative to its parent*. You will need to define a height for each ancestor up to and including the `html` and `body` elements:

```css
html,body,
div#wrapper,
div#page-content-wrapper {
    height:100%;
}
```

Also, you are missing a semi-colon after the height definition for `.fill`:

```
.fill {
    height:100%;
    background:darkblue;
}
```

Here's a [WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tjno281a/).

(It's off-site since I had trouble fitting this into a runnable snippet.)

Answer (score 0):

set the height to 100% in the class col-lg-12

Answer (score 0):

You will basically go away with height:100% in your code, and try this

```
background-image: url("image.gif");
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you wish is for the entire page to have a darkblue background, simply apply the "background:darkblue;" property and value to your "body selector"

ie:

`body {
    background-color:darkblue;
}`